# Changing ATS settings causes my app to hang - Metro builds but app doesn't start

Tags: ios, react-native, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

I'm building a react-native app for iOS and my backend API doesn't currently have SSL configured so I need to add an exception to ATS.

Before I change anything in info.plist, the app loads but any API calls don't work because they are blocked. When I do edit the info.plist to add my domain as an exception, like below, the app builds but then it doesn't run on the simulator. All i get is a white screen: I have screen shots below of what happens before and after i change my settings. Not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

.

[image: before i change my settings it loads]

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mysite.com</key>
            <dict>
          <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

[image: after i change my setting it doesn't load]

Comment: Can you show the console error where it says ATS is blocking the URL?  Why do you set a min TLS version if you don't have SSL configured? That is only needed if you support HTTPS, but only the older TLS 1.1.  I'm assuming you are trying to hit your site without https (e.g. `http://www.example.com`)?

Comment: Also, have you tried just disabling ATS altogether (not just for your domain) with the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` setting?  That could help confirm it is an ATS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. Was swapping the keys the thing that should have made a difference? Also the spacing doesn't matter right? Or does incorrect indentation make a difference?

Comment: this is not swapping, this is changing from `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads ` to `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`